# Access Form layout and design: Header: How do I make my header section look like Google

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I would like to rip off Google's design for my Continuous Form.  The detail section of the form is set up to display N number of records resulting from a search, and thus cannot be used to create this effect (i think).  Everything must go in the header section.

[image: Google header image]

there are 2 primary issues I would like to address in this question:

1. Two toned background.  The header section should have a grey stripe and a white stripe.  This stripe needs to extend the full width of the form, which is variable and will depend on the user. (i'm using tabs not pop-ups)
2. How to right justify certain elements of the header so that they stay close to the right edge, wherever that may fall, just like your account information on Google.

The "Search Results" in the detail section are loaded by setting the form's recordSource to the results of a query defined in VBA, which takes parameters from the search box.  The form is continuous.

Any ideas how to hack this into place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the background, use two rectangles with transparent borders, one back color gray, one white.  You can size them to the form by using the form's `InsideWidth` property.  For example:

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    rect1.Width = Me.InsideWidth
    rect2.Width = Me.InsideWidth
End Sub
```

I would do a similar thing for the buttons/images/etc you want right justified.  Set their `Left` property relative to the form's width:

```
mySettingsButton.Left = Me.InsideWidth - 300
```

Keep in mind all the measurements are twips (1440 twips/inch)

Comment: Who you callin' a Twip? ... Nah, j/k.  Boss answer.  Exactly what I needed.  So many freakin' variables for every single object in Access, who can keep track of them all.  Microsoft can't seem to.  Thank you Sir.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to the one given by HansUp, as it seems to be a more standard (or intended) way of doing this.  I still love your answer, though.  Many possible uses for it.

Comment: So, it turns out that Rect and Line objects don't have a resize option, so it looks like I have to use Inside width, after all.  You win!  Implemented with full success.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of MS Access provide improved form layout features when using the ACCDB database file format.

The screen captures below are based on a form in Access 2010.  The second image is after the form width was expanded, but it's scaled down for display on this web page.  However you can open those images directly to compare their relative widths.

The grey color is from the form header's Back Color property.  The white box is a simple text box whose Back Color is white and Back Style is Normal (not Transparent).

The text box's Horizontal Anchor property is Both, and its Can Grow property is Yes.  The other 3 items ("?", "Button 2", and "Button 3") are command buttons.  Their Horizontal Anchors are set to Right and their Can Grow properties are No.

[image]

[image]

The result of those properties is that when the form expands, those command buttons maintain their size are are kept right-aligned within the form.  And the text box stretches to fill the remaining available space.

Note this behavior is accomplished without any VBA code.

I think these layout capabilities were introduced in Access 2007 and perhaps refined in 2010.

Comment: Wow, nice.  That is cool.  I assume that I can use those same resize settings on a rectangle object to get the two toned stripe effect as well.  Very nice, thank you!

Comment: As a former web dev guy, I'm now wondering if there is a way to set a repeating or horizontally stretched image as the background to the header.  Not that these solutions won't work for the 2 toned background, but can do even crazier stuff with a BG image.

Comment: I added an image control to my form, but then found the Can Grow property is not supported for that control type.  So I don't see how to do what you want for an image using only layout features.  Alternatively, you could adjust the image control dimensions with VBA code as Mike demonstrated.

Comment: BG image can go on the form.  Haven't played with it, but here is a link: http://www.functionx.com/access/Lesson11.htm